# In Night at the Museum, what do the mannequins know about the people they portray?

Tags: night-at-the-museum

In *Night a the Museum* the exhibits in the American Museum of Natural History comes alive at night. Some of them, like the mummy of Pharaoh Akhmenrah, are real historical objects / people. Others, like Teddy Roosevelt, are mannequins.

> "Actually, I never did any of those things. Teddy Roosevelt did. I was made in a mannequin factory in Poughkeepsie."

Teddy dispenses Rooseveltian wisdom, but knows he isn't really the former president.
Yet Attila the Hun and his fellow Huns don't seem to be aware they aren't actual Huns. Attila even responds to Larry's pseudo-psycho therapy.
The cavemen, who can't even speak but only grunt, don't seem to be aware of their origins either.

Larry tells Rebecca to go talk to Sacagawea for her dissertation. But how helpful would she have been, probably coming from the same mannequin factory in Poughkeepsie where Teddy came from?

**What do the mannequins *really* know about the lives and characters of the people they portray?**

Comment: Perhaps there's something special about Poughkeepsie? Perhaps Attilla was made in Cleveland?

Comment: At the very least she's heard nearly 50 years of people talking about her.

Comment: The way I understood it was that all the wax figures thought they were the real people at first. Such was the nature of the magic that made them come alive. The didn't simply come alive physically, but also in spirit. But most of they quickly figured out that they were in fact, wax figures. (The fact that they always came awake in a display in a museum would have been a giveaway.) So in fact, they real question should be: how did Roosevelt knew he was made in Poughkeepsie?

Comment: He (was barely able to) read it. It was stamped on his left buttock.

Comment: [Poughkeepsie](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34361805#34361805) is an [inherently funny place name](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSdV12FhNR0&feature=youtu.be&t=7m47s).