# Why doesn't Darth Vader's force-choke work and where is his lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, night-at-the-museum

In *Night at the Museum: Battle of the Smithsonian*, we see Darth Vader wanting to join the bad guys (Pharaoh Kahmunrah, Napoleon Bonaparte, and Al Capone). He attempts a force-choke, which has no effect and is then ridiculed by Kahmunrah for his appearance.

**Why didn't his force-choke work? And where is his lightsaber?**

Note that pictures come to life to the point of being able to enter them and that vehicles seem to have a full tank and to be ready to go.
In other words, they come to life to the *idea* of what they represent.

Comment: His force choke doesn't work because the Force isn't real.

Comment: Because he's there just as comic relief?

Comment: This has been VTC as "off-topic, could someone explain to me who this is off-topic?

Comment: Hells yeah! Just because it isn't Star Wars doesn't mean the Force shouldn't work! There's a true Star Wars fan :D

Comment: Mannequins don't have midichlorians, silly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, my understanding of The Force, from Star Wars, is that it is something "that surrounds and penetrates all living things."  In other words, Force powers work by manipulating an invisible *something* that is present in all living things.  Darth Vader may have come to life is all his glory, but *The Force itself is not real,* therefore there is nothing for Darth Vader's Force Choke power to work on in the real world, and thus it fails to have any effect.

As for not pulling out his lightsaber, chalk it up to the writers wanting the good guys to have a fighting chance.  Just from watching the trailer you linked, I don't actually see his lightsaber on his belt - maybe the mannequin of Vader didn't have a prop lightsaber?  If so, then he wouldn't have one when he came to life, either.

Comment: Saber skills could be chalked up to being force sensitive, so he may not be that good of a fighter with it anyway....

Comment: @Malachi Gen. Grievous had his skills programmed in and he was able to kill several Jedi despite being force-insensitive.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein, I wish I still had the source (probably noncanonical, now, anyway) but the lightsabre only requires force sensitivity for *safe* use. Those untrained in the force could just as quickly lop off their own arms, as the sabre requires great skill, and can naturally cut through organic matter with great ease. IIRC, this is true to its origin of being based off ancient samurai katanas, which followed the same basic rules. This is a non event with a robot, who as mentioned, is programmed to be precise. Humans, on the other hand, are not so precise.

Answer (score 8):

As covered by you and @Mr Lister in [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148467/in-night-at-the-museum-what-do-the-mannequins-know-about-the-people-they-portra), like Robin Williams' character he probably realizes he's a mannequin.  So no Force Choke for him, I'm sure, much to his consternation. But that doesn't stop him from trying in the hopes it might work.  As to his Lightsaber, he realizes he's a mannequin so also probably realizes his Lightsaber is not real either.  So he refuses to get laughed at, even more, by trying to whip that bad boy out and light er up.

Comment: Poor Vader. First he lost much of his body, and became a shadow of the man he used to be. Now he's resurrected as _this_, and even what he had before has now been taken away from him.